# For honor neutral bot

Tags: for-honor

How to set up a duel with a neutral bot? I only see the option for setting bot level.

I can only set up duels with hostile bots in custom match but I've heard that other people can duel neutral bots to practice combo. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There do not seem to be just practice dummys that you can practice on. Every practice mode has AI of some sort in them.

There are 4 practice modes currently:

**Practice:**

> Practice Mode allows players to revisit the tutorial they played when
>   they started their game for the first time.

**Advanced Practice:**

> Advanced Practice Mode skips the basics and moves directly into
>   attack moves, starting with how to interrupt a Guard Break.

**Free Mode:**

> Free Mode is a practice mode that bears similarity to Dominion in that
>   there are two teams of four fighting over three zones.

**Duel Practice:**

> In Duel Practice, the player is matched with an AI warrior and as in
>   1v1, the winner is the best of five rounds.

Comment: I was confusing Custom match mode with practice mode. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Duel Practice doesn't work the same way for me as it does for you it seems. I added an answer with more explanation. Perhaps we're playing on different platforms?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [the answer by n_palum](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/300985/97591) it might help to explain a bit about the Duel Practice mode.

In it you can choose 4 difficulties of bots, to fight endlessly.
If you die in this mode or if your opponent dies, you simply respawn after a few seconds.

[image]

The difficulties 1 to 3 are differing levels of skill for the bots.
Difficulty 0 however, is simply a bot that runs up to you and doesn't fight back.
If you want to test combos, a difficulty 0 bot is a good way to practice without interruptions.

This mode doesn't require you to unlock any heroes, so you can even use it to test out other classes.
Or try out combo's you've had used against you, to figure out their flow.

Comment: Yes the level 0 bot is neutral. they dont attack you so you can practice on them.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the practice modes that n_palum has already mentioned in his answer there is one way to practice that I find very useful for trying new characters and/or combos.

**Infinite custom duels**

In the rules and options menu for a custom game you can define how the game works. You can set the timer to infinte and the damage taken to none if you select the leftmost option in the bar.

Additionally you will be able to select a bot with an AI level. 1 is pretty much a target dummy that occasionally blocks/hits you while 3 is comparable to a player that somewhat knows what he's doing.

The reason I prefer this method is because you can select your opponent which allows you to practice vs a specific moveset while not having to wait for rounds to start since the game is basically infinte. **You can still die by falling off cliffs though**.

Another thing that works really well for practicing is using the same rules with a friend who controls the opponent. If you are in a voicecomm together you can tell him exactly what move you want to practice and what he should do.